# Webpack Karma Typescript -- Module not found

Tags: typescript, webpack, karma-runner, vuejs2, karma-mocha

I'm relative new to the JavaScript and TypeScript ecosystem and try to set up a good template project which will get me started in new projects quickly. I also want to understand how everything works under the hood, so I don't want to use just another template project (which I didn't find for my needs anyway).

I'm using Vue.js 2, webpack 3, TypeScript 2, karma, mocha and chai. **My template project works except for the tests.**

You can find the whole project here: https://github.com/MoePad/javascript-template-project/tree/karma-mocha-hell  (branch karma-mocha-hell; which this link will lead to). You can check it out and run `npm run karma-test` for running the tests (or `npm run dev` to see that everything else is running correctly).

### errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/main/vue-setup.d.ts
Module parse failed: ~/test/src/main/vue-setup.d.ts Unexpected token (1:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| declare module '*.vue' {
|   import Vue from 'vue'
|   export default Vue

ERROR in ./src/main/App.vue
Module parse failed: ~/test/src/main/App.vue Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|   <div>
|     <h1>My new app: {{message}}</h1>
```

And so. This leads me to the assumption, that something is wrong with my loaders (as suggested in the error message).

### My project structure

(only the things related to this problem; ie. omitting .gitignore etc):

```
config/karma/karma.conf.js
config/karma/index.js
config/webpack/[WEBPACK CONFIGS]
config/commons.ts
src/main/[PRODUCTION CODE]
src/test/[TEST CODE]
tsconfig.json
package.json
```

### karma.conf.ts:

```
var testConfig = require('../webpack/webpack.test.conf')

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../..',
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    exclude: ['node_modules'],
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'karma-typescript'],
    // this is the entry file for all our tests.
    files: [
      {pattern: 'src/test/**/*.ktest0.ts', watch: false},
      {pattern: 'src/main/**/*.ts', watch: false},
      {pattern: 'src/main/**/*.vue', watch: false},
      {pattern: './config/karma/index.js', watched: false}
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        './config/karma/index.js': ['coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap'],
        //'./src/**/*.ts': ['coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap']
         './src/**/*.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
         './src/**/*.vue': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
      //  '*.ts': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: {
      module: testConfig.module,
      resolve: testConfig.resolve
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    singleRun: true,
    //logLevel: 'debug',
    reporters: ['progress'],
    colors: true,
    port: 9090,
    karmaTypescriptConfig: {
      compilerOptions: {
        module: "commonjs"
      },
      tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
    }
  })
}
```

### tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "lib": [
          "dom",
          "es2015",
          "es2016"
      ],
      "jsx": "preserve",
      "target": "es2016",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
      "./src/**/*",
      "./config/commons.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

### webpack.base.conf

```
import * as HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import commons from '../commons'
import * as Dashboard from 'webpack-dashboard/plugin'

export default {
  entry: {
    app: commons.resolve('src/main/main.ts')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      '@': commons.resolve('src/main')
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       template: 'src/main/index.html',
       inject: true
    }),
    new Dashboard()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        include: [commons.resolve('src')/*, commons.resolve('config')*/],
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        include: [commons.resolve('src')],
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          esModule: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### webpack.test.conf

```
import * as merge from 'webpack-merge'
//import baseConfig from './webpack.base.conf'
import baseConfig from './webpack.base.conf'
import commons from '../commons'
import * as nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals'
import * as webpack from 'webpack'

//baseConfig.entry = undefined
//baseConfig.plugins = undefined

const devConfig = merge(baseConfig, {
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
//  resolve: {
//    alias: {
//      '--': commons.resolve('src/main/test')
//    }
//  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"test"'
      }
    })
  ],
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: commons.resolve('src/main'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
})

export default devConfig
```

### commons.ts

```
import * as open from 'open'
import * as path from 'path'

declare var __dirname: any

export function resolve(dir: any) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

export default {resolve, open}
```

### Summary

I tried almost every combination of changing the settings. I tried moving the configuration files themselves. I was searching almost a whole day to find a solution. Nothing I could find helps. But I think I'm really close to get this thing running. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Those are webpack / Babel errors that happen when webpack is mistakenly configured to load your typescript files directly with Babel instead of pre-processing them with a typescript loader. I think you can fix this by just adding `.d.ts` to your resolve extensions

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried it, although Babel is not involved. It didn't do the trick :(
My understanding is, that I need to preprocess all my files with webpack before passing it to karma (because karma could not process TypeScript itself), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was one major problem:

```
externals: [nodeExternals()],
```

after I removed this line the code was running correctly.

//edit: for a running version please see: https://github.com/MoePad/javascript-template-project/tree/vue-js-typescript (latest commit while I wrote this: 46b0755)

Comment: In case it helps somebody who comes across this later, you probably shouldn't be using `karma-typescript` and `karma-webpack` at the same time.  I believe you're supposed to use the former as a preprocessor, where your sample config in the question uses `"webpack"` -- this would mean that `karma-typescript` isn't actually doing anything, and can be removed.  You could skip `karma-webpack` and use `karma-typescript` instead, if you wanted, but I couldn't get module resolution working correctly using transpilation alone.